# Utilizing nested try / except inside if statement of while loop

Tags: python

Coding on a binary2decimal and vice versa converter. Works so far but trying to handle a exception if someone types in a letter instead of a decimal. Wished outcome would be to stay inside the decimal to binary part of the code and not jump back completely to the beginning of the while loop. This is what I've come up so far:

```
# TASK #
# Binary to Decimal and Back Converter
# Develop a converter to convert a decimal
# number to binary or a binary number to its
# decimal equivalent.

# ask user which conversion needs to be performed
print('1: Binary to decimal?')
print('2: Decimal to binary?') 

active = True

while active:

    usr_input = int(input('Please choose which conversion needs to be preformed (Type 1 or 2): '))

    # binary to decimal conversion happens here
    if usr_input == 1:
        bin_num = input('Please type in a binary number of your choice: ')
        dec_res = int(bin_num, 2)
        print("The binary '%s' converted to decimal is: '%s'" % (bin_num, dec_res))
        break

    # decimal to binary converion happens here
    elif usr_input == 2:
        try:    # check if letter gets typed in. If binary then proceed normally
            dec_num = int(input('Please type in a decimal number of your choice: '))
            bin_res = bin(dec_num)
            print("The decimal '%s' converted to binary is: '%s'" % (dec_num, str(bin_res[2:])))
            break
        except ValueError: # if letter then...
            print('You can only type in decimals, no letters. Try again...')
            
    else:
        print('You can only choose between numbers 1 and 2. Try again...')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you can simply add a `while True:` and encapsulate the `try except` statement, like this

```py
elif usr_input == 2:
    while True:
        try:    # check if letter gets typed in. If binary then proceed normally
            dec_num = int(input('Please type in a decimal number of your choice: '))
            bin_res = bin(dec_num)
            print("The decimal '%s' converted to binary is: '%s'" % (dec_num, str(bin_res[2:])))
            break
        except ValueError: # if letter then...
            print('You can only type in decimals, no letters. Try again...')

    break
```

That way, until a valid input is given and you break the while loop, the program will keep asking for an input. The last `break` statement is to break the outer `while` loop, as I'm assuming that's what the `break` inside the `try` statement was for.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer as the solution, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
print('1: Binary to decimal?')
print('2: Decimal to binary?') 

active = True

while active:

usr_input = int(input('Please choose which conversion needs to be preformed (Type 1 or 2): '))

# binary to decimal conversion happens here
if usr_input == 1:
    bin_num = input('Please type in a binary number of your choice: ')
    dec_res = int(bin_num, 2)
    print("The binary '%s' converted to decimal is: '%s'" % (bin_num, dec_res))
    break

# decimal to binary converion happens here
elif usr_input == 2:
    while True:
      try:    # check if letter gets typed in. If binary then proceed normally
          dec_num = int(input('Please type in a decimal number of your choice: '))
          bin_res = bin(dec_num)
          print("The decimal '%s' converted to binary is: '%s'" % (dec_num, str(bin_res[2:])))
          break
      except ValueError: # if letter then...
          print('You can only type in decimals, no letters. Try again...')
          continue
      else:
          break    
        
else:
    print('You can only choose between numbers 1 and 2. Try again...')
```

The logic to use input the decimal number until user enters correct decimal

Comment: The `continue; else: break` seems kind of redundant (you already `break` at the end of `try` and `continue` would be the last statement in the loop)

Comment: @tobias_k
I agree. Nevertheless needed a break statement on the inner while True level to not get stuck in the decimal to binary conversion part and instead exit the program. That's exactly how I wanted it.

Thanks for the hints guys! Really appreciate that.